# Microsoft Speech recognition SRGS

Tags: c#

I've been creating a speech recognition uwp app using Windows speech sdk. I've been walking through the example from this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378355(v=office.14).aspx 
It works just fine but out curiosity I want to see if speech would be recognized from using any combination of words in the play command eg 'the play item' ...now the correct combination should be 'play the item' and any other combination of the words should not be picked as a match by the sdk. Funny enough the sdk is picking up any combination of the rule items. My question is, how can I stop it from  picking any combination of the rule items cause from the tutorial it's not supposed to work like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom grammar such as if statements. For example this is from my Digital Assistant and if you want some better examples let me know what you need.

```
    SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    SpeechSynthesizer Alexis = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    SpeechRecognitionEngine startlistening = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    DateTime timenow = DateTime.Now;
```

and then you can access custom grammar using case statements

```
 case "hello":
 case "hello alexis":
 timenow = DateTime.Now;
 if (timenow.Hour >= 5 && timenow.Hour < 12)
 { Alexis.SpeakAsync("Goodmorning " + Settings.Default.User); }
 if (timenow.Hour >= 12 && timenow.Hour < 18)
 { Alexis.SpeakAsync("Good afternoon " + Settings.Default.User); }
 if (timenow.Hour >= 18 && timenow.Hour < 24)
 { Alexis.SpeakAsync("Good evening " + Settings.Default.User); }
 if (timenow.Hour < 5)
 { Alexis.SpeakAsync("Hello " + Settings.Default.User + ", it's getting late"); }
 break;
```

or you can use `if statements` such as this

```
string speech = e.Result.Text;
if (speech == ".....")
  {
      Alexis.SpeakAsync("....");
  }
```

you can do coding anyway you want such as accessing programs or opening up files or websites. You can also do music directories and pictures. his is just an example for you to get an idea.

What ever you use as grammar you can implement it as default or you can do what I did with Alexis (DLA) I gave a custom command section with richTextBoxes. I created the directory and loaded/unloaded grammars in to the path.

```
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands");
        Settings.Default.ShellC = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Shell Commands.txt";
        Settings.Default.ShellR = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Shell Response.txt";
        Settings.Default.ShellL = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Shell Location.txt";
        Settings.Default.WebC = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Web Commands.txt";
        Settings.Default.WebR = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Web Response.txt";
        Settings.Default.WebL = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Web URL.txt";
        Settings.Default.SocC = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Social Commands.txt";
        Settings.Default.SocR = @"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents\\Alexis Custom Commands\\Social Response.txt";
        Settings.Default.Save();

        scpath = Settings.Default.ShellC;
        srpath = Settings.Default.ShellR;
        slpath = Settings.Default.ShellL;
        webcpath = Settings.Default.WebC;
        webrpath = Settings.Default.WebR;
        weblpath = Settings.Default.WebL;
        socpath = Settings.Default.SocC;
        sorpath = Settings.Default.SocR;


        if (!File.Exists(scpath))
        { sw = File.CreateText(scpath); sw.Write("My Documents"); sw.Close(); }
        if (!File.Exists(srpath))
        { sw = File.CreateText(srpath); sw.Write("Right away"); sw.Close(); }
        if (!File.Exists(slpath))
        { sw = File.CreateText(slpath); sw.Write(@"C:\Users\" + userName + "\\Documents"); sw.Close(); }
        if (!File.Exists(webcpath))
        { sw = File.CreateText(webcpath); sw.Write("Open Google"); sw.Close(); }
        if (!File.Exists(webrpath))
        { sw = File.CreateText(webrpath); sw.Write("Very well"); sw.Close(); }
        if (!File.Exists(weblpath))
        { sw = File.CreateText(weblpath); sw.Write("http://www.google.com"); sw.Close(); }
        if (!File.Exists(socpath))
        { sw = File.CreateText(socpath); sw.Write("How are you"); sw.Close(); }
        if (!File.Exists(sorpath))
        { sw = File.CreateText(sorpath); sw.Write("I'm doing well thanks for asking"); sw.Close(); }



        ArrayShellCommands = File.ReadAllLines(scpath);
        ArrayShellResponse = File.ReadAllLines(srpath);
        ArrayShellLocation = File.ReadAllLines(slpath);
        ArrayWebCommands = File.ReadAllLines(webcpath);
        ArrayWebResponse = File.ReadAllLines(webrpath);
        ArrayWebURL = File.ReadAllLines(weblpath);
        ArraySocialCommands = File.ReadAllLines(socpath);
        ArraySocialResponse = File.ReadAllLines(sorpath);


        try
        { shellcommandgrammar = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(ArrayShellCommands))); _recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(shellcommandgrammar); }
        catch
        { Alexis.SpeakAsync("I've detected an in valid entry in your computer commands, possibly a blank line. Computer commands will cease to work until it is fixed."); }
        try
        { webcommandgrammar = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(ArrayWebCommands))); _recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(webcommandgrammar); }
        catch
        { Alexis.SpeakAsync("I've detected an in valid entry in your web commands, possibly a blank line. Web commands will cease to work until it is fixed."); }
        try
        { socialcommandgrammar = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(ArraySocialCommands))); _recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(socialcommandgrammar); }
        catch
        { Alexis.SpeakAsync("I've detected an in valid entry in your social commands, possibly a blank line. Social commands will cease to work until it is fixed."); }



    }
```

this is just something to go by for example and something to think about.

Comment: Thanks a lot campnerd, I this this will work even better than using an SRGS file. This seems cleaner and I can implement more logic from code in this. One last question though. how can I archive speaker interaction for example speaker want to send an email to 'John' and 3 'John Contacts' and asks the user which John 1st, 2nd or 3rd, then the user selectes 3rd and continues with reading the text out then send.

Comment: Like an Alarm clock. When I set my alarm I just say, "Alexis set the alarm." then Alexis asks what time, then I say a time... Is this what you mean

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean

Comment: @control look at the second answer. Also you can click on my profile and then go to my website. It has useful information on AI research and voice applications.

Answer (score 0):

you can access string arrays like this example of setting my alarm aclock. I use string arrays.

```
using Alexis.Properties;
```

then I add the string array and settings properties

```
   String[] AlarmAM = { "1:00 AM", "1:01 AM", "1:02 AM", "1:03 AM", "1:04 AM", "1:05 AM", "1:06 AM", "1:07 AM", "1:08 AM", "1:09 AM", "1:10 AM", "1:11 AM", "1:12 AM", "1:13 AM", "1:14 AM", "1:15 AM", "1:16 AM", "1:17 AM", "1:18 AM", "1:19 AM", "1:20 AM", "1:21 AM", "1:22 AM", "1:23 AM", "1:24 AM", "1:25 AM", "1:26 AM", "1:27 AM", "1:28 AM", "1:29 AM", "1:30 AM", "1:31 AM", "1:32 AM", "1:33 AM", "1:34 AM", "1:35 AM", "1:36 AM", "1:37 AM", "1:38 AM", "1:39 AM", "1:40 AM", "1:41 AM", "1:42 AM", "1:43 AM", "1:44 AM", "1:45 AM", "1:46 AM", "1:47 AM", "1:48 AM", "1:49 AM", "1:50 AM", "1:51 AM", "1:52 AM", "1:53 AM", "1:54 AM", "1:55 AM", "1:56 AM", "1:57 AM", "1:58 AM", "1:59 AM", "2:00 AM", "2:01 AM", "2:02 AM", "2:03 AM", "2:04 AM", "2:05 AM", "2:06 AM", "2:07 AM", "2:08 AM", "2:09 AM", "2:10 AM", "2:11 AM", "2:12 AM", "2:13 AM", "2:14 AM", "2:15 AM", "2:16 AM", "2:17 AM", "2:18 AM", "2:19 AM", "2:20 AM", "2:21 AM", "2:22 AM", "2:23 AM", "2:24 AM", "2:25 AM", "2:26 AM", "2:27 AM", "2:28 AM", "2:29 AM", "2:30 AM", "2:31 AM", "2:32 AM", "2:33 AM", "2:34 AM", "2:35 AM", "2:36 AM", "2:37 AM", "2:38 AM", "2:39 AM", "2:40 AM", "2:41 AM", "2:42 AM", "2:43 AM", "2:44 AM", "2:45 AM", "2:46 AM", "2:47 AM", "2:48 AM", "2:49 AM", "2:50 AM", "2:51 AM", "2:52 AM", "2:53 AM", "2:54 AM", "2:55 AM", "2:56 AM", "2:57 AM", "2:58 AM", "2:59 AM", "3:00 AM", "3:01 AM", "3:02 AM", "3:03 AM", "3:04 AM", "3:05 AM", "3:06 AM", "3:07 AM", "3:08 AM", "3:09 AM", "3:10 AM", "3:11 AM", "3:12 AM", "3:13 AM", "3:14 AM", "3:15 AM", "3:16 AM", "3:17 AM", "3:18 AM", "3:19 AM", "3:20 AM", "3:21 AM", "3:22 AM", "3:23 AM", "3:24 AM", "3:25 AM", "3:26 AM", "3:27 AM", "3:28 AM", "3:29 AM", "3:30 AM", "3:31 AM", "3:32 AM", "3:33 AM", "3:34 AM", "3:35 AM", "3:36 AM", "3:37 AM", "3:38 AM", "3:39 AM", "3:40 AM", "3:41 AM", "3:42 AM", "3:43 AM", "3:44 AM", "3:45 AM", "3:46 AM", "3:47 AM", "3:48 AM", "3:49 AM", "3:50 AM", "3:51 AM", "3:52 AM", "3:53 AM", "3:54 AM", "3:55 AM", "3:56 AM", "3:57 AM", "3:58 AM", "3:59 AM", "4:00 AM", "4:01 AM", "4:02 AM", "4:03 AM", "4:04 AM", "4:05 AM", "4:06 AM", "4:07 AM", "4:08 AM", "4:09 AM", "4:10 AM", "4:11 AM", "4:12 AM", "4:13 AM", "4:14 AM", "4:15 AM", "4:16 AM", "4:17 AM", "4:18 AM", "4:19 AM", "4:20 AM", "4:21 AM", "4:22 AM", "4:23 AM", "4:24 AM", "4:25 AM", "4:26 AM", "4:27 AM", "4:28 AM", "4:29 AM", "4:30 AM", "4:31 AM", "4:32 AM", "4:33 AM", "4:34 AM", "4:35 AM", "4:36 AM", "4:37 AM", "4:38 AM", "4:39 AM", "4:40 AM", "4:41 AM", "4:42 AM", "4:43 AM", "4:44 AM", "4:45 AM", "4:46 AM", "4:47 AM", "4:48 AM", "4:49 AM", "4:50 AM", "4:51 AM", "4:52 AM", "4:53 AM", "4:54 AM", "4:55 AM", "4:56 AM", "4:57 AM", "4:58 AM", "4:59 AM", "5:00 AM", "5:01 AM", "5:02 AM", "5:03 AM", "5:04 AM", "5:05 AM", "5:06 AM", "5:07 AM", "5:08 AM", "5:09 AM", "5:10 AM", "5:11 AM", "5:12 AM", "5:13 AM", "5:14 AM", "5:15 AM", "5:16 AM", "5:17 AM", "5:18 AM", "5:19 AM", "5:20 AM", "5:21 AM", "5:22 AM", "5:23 AM", "5:24 AM", "5:25 AM", "5:26 AM", "5:27 AM", "5:28 AM", "5:29 AM", "5:30 AM", "5:31 AM", "5:32 AM", "5:33 AM", "5:34 AM", "5:35 AM", "5:36 AM", "5:37 AM", "5:38 AM", "5:39 AM", "5:40 AM", "5:41 AM", "5:42 AM", "5:43 AM", "5:44 AM", "5:45 AM", "5:46 AM", "5:47 AM", "5:48 AM", "5:49 AM", "5:50 AM", "5:51 AM", "5:52 AM", "5:53 AM", "5:54 AM", "5:55 AM", "5:56 AM", "5:57 AM", "5:58 AM", "5:59 AM", "6:00 AM", "6:01 AM", "6:02 AM", "6:03 AM", "6:04 AM", "6:05 AM", "6:06 AM", "6:07 AM", "6:08 AM", "6:09 AM", "6:10 AM", "6:11 AM", "6:12 AM", "6:13 AM", "6:14 AM", "6:15 AM", "6:16 AM", "6:17 AM", "6:18 AM", "6:19 AM", "6:20 AM", "6:21 AM", "6:22 AM", "6:23 AM", "6:24 AM", "6:25 AM", "6:26 AM", "6:27 AM", "6:28 AM", "6:29 AM", "6:30 AM", "6:31 AM", "6:32 AM", "6:33 AM", "6:34 AM", "6:35 AM", "6:36 AM", "6:37 AM", "6:38 AM", "6:39 AM", "6:40 AM", "6:41 AM", "6:42 AM", "6:43 AM", "6:44 AM", "6:45 AM", "6:46 AM", "6:47 AM", "6:48 AM", "6:49 AM", "6:50 AM", "6:51 AM", "6:52 AM", "6:53 AM", "6:54 AM", "6:55 AM", "6:56 AM", "6:57 AM", "6:58 AM", "6:59 AM", "7:00 AM", "7:01 AM", "7:02 AM", "7:03 AM", "7:04 AM", "7:05 AM", "7:06 AM", "7:07 AM", "7:08 AM", "7:09 AM", "7:10 AM", "7:11 AM", "7:12 AM", "7:13 AM", "7:14 AM", "7:15 AM", "7:16 AM", "7:17 AM", "7:18 AM", "7:19 AM", "7:20 AM", "7:21 AM", "7:22 AM", "7:23 AM", "7:24 AM", "7:25 AM", "7:26 AM", "7:27 AM", "7:28 AM", "7:29 AM", "7:30 AM", "7:31 AM", "7:32 AM", "7:33 AM", "7:34 AM", "7:35 AM", "7:36 AM", "7:37 AM", "7:38 AM", "7:39 AM", "7:40 AM", "7:41 AM", "7:42 AM", "7:43 AM", "7:44 AM", "7:45 AM", "7:46 AM", "7:47 AM", "7:48 AM", "7:49 AM", "7:50 AM", "7:51 AM", "7:52 AM", "7:53 AM", "7:54 AM", "7:55 AM", "7:56 AM", "7:57 AM", "7:58 AM", "7:59 AM", "8:00 AM", "8:01 AM", "8:02 AM", "8:03 AM", "8:04 AM", "8:05 AM", "8:06 AM", "8:07 AM", "8:08 AM", "8:09 AM", "8:10 AM", "8:11 AM", "8:12 AM", "8:13 AM", "8:14 AM", "8:15 AM", "8:16 AM", "8:17 AM", "8:18 AM", "8:19 AM", "8:20 AM", "8:21 AM", "8:22 AM", "8:23 AM", "8:24 AM", "8:25 AM", "8:26 AM", "8:27 AM", "8:28 AM", "8:29 AM", "8:30 AM", "8:31 AM", "8:32 AM", "8:33 AM", "8:34 AM", "8:35 AM", "8:36 AM", "8:37 AM", "8:38 AM", "8:39 AM", "8:40 AM", "8:41 AM", "8:42 AM", "8:43 AM", "8:44 AM", "8:45 AM", "8:46 AM", "8:47 AM", "8:48 AM", "8:49 AM", "8:50 AM", "8:51 AM", "8:52 AM", "8:53 AM", "8:54 AM", "8:55 AM", "8:56 AM", "8:57 AM", "8:58 AM", "8:59 AM", "9:00 AM", "9:01 AM", "9:02 AM", "9:03 AM", "9:04 AM", "9:05 AM", "9:06 AM", "9:07 AM", "9:08 AM", "9:09 AM", "9:10 AM", "9:11 AM", "9:12 AM", "9:13 AM", "9:14 AM", "9:15 AM", "9:16 AM", "9:17 AM", "9:18 AM", "9:19 AM", "9:20 AM", "9:21 AM", "9:22 AM", "9:23 AM", "9:24 AM", "9:25 AM", "9:26 AM", "9:27 AM", "9:28 AM", "9:29 AM", "9:30 AM", "9:31 AM", "9:32 AM", "9:33 AM", "9:34 AM", "9:35 AM", "9:36 AM", "9:37 AM", "9:38 AM", "9:39 AM", "9:40 AM", "9:41 AM", "9:42 AM", "9:43 AM", "9:44 AM", "9:45 AM", "9:46 AM", "9:47 AM", "9:48 AM", "9:49 AM", "9:50 AM", "9:51 AM", "9:52 AM", "9:53 AM", "9:54 AM", "9:55 AM", "9:56 AM", "9:57 AM", "9:58 AM", "9:59 AM", "10:00 AM", "10:01 AM", "10:02 AM", "10:03 AM", "10:04 AM", "10:05 AM", "10:06 AM", "10:07 AM", "10:08 AM", "10:09 AM", "10:10 AM", "10:11 AM", "10:12 AM", "10:13 AM", "10:14 AM", "10:15 AM", "10:16 AM", "10:17 AM", "10:18 AM", "10:19 AM", "10:20 AM", "10:21 AM", "10:22 AM", "10:23 AM", "10:24 AM", "10:25 AM", "10:26 AM", "10:27 AM", "10:28 AM", "10:29 AM", "10:30 AM", "10:31 AM", "10:32 AM", "10:33 AM", "10:34 AM", "10:35 AM", "10:36 AM", "10:37 AM", "10:38 AM", "10:39 AM", "10:40 AM", "10:41 AM", "10:42 AM", "10:43 AM", "10:44 AM", "10:45 AM", "10:46 AM", "10:47 AM", "10:48 AM", "10:49 AM", "10:50 AM", "10:51 AM", "10:52 AM", "10:53 AM", "10:54 AM", "10:55 AM", "10:56 AM", "10:57 AM", "10:58 AM", "10:59 AM", "11:00 AM", "11:01 AM", "11:02 AM", "11:03 AM", "11:04 AM", "11:05 AM", "11:06 AM", "11:07 AM", "11:08 AM", "11:09 AM", "11:10 AM", "11:11 AM", "11:12 AM", "11:13 AM", "11:14 AM", "11:15 AM", "11:16 AM", "11:17 AM", "11:18 AM", "11:19 AM", "11:20 AM", "11:21 AM", "11:22 AM", "11:23 AM", "11:24 AM", "11:25 AM", "11:26 AM", "11:27 AM", "11:28 AM", "11:29 AM", "11:30 AM", "11:31 AM", "11:32 AM", "11:33 AM", "11:34 AM", "11:35 AM", "11:36 AM", "11:37 AM", "11:38 AM", "11:39 AM", "11:40 AM", "11:41 AM", "11:42 AM", "11:43 AM", "11:44 AM", "11:45 AM", "11:46 AM", "11:47 AM", "11:48 AM", "11:49 AM", "11:50 AM", "11:51 AM", "11:52 AM", "11:53 AM", "11:54 AM", "11:55 AM", "11:56 AM", "11:57 AM", "11:58 AM", "11:59 AM", "12:00 AM", "12:01 AM", "12:02 AM", "12:03 AM", "12:04 AM", "12:05 AM", "12:06 AM", "12:07 AM", "12:08 AM", "12:09 AM", "12:10 AM", "12:11 AM", "12:12 AM", "12:13 AM", "12:14 AM", "12:15 AM", "12:16 AM", "12:17 AM", "12:18 AM", "12:19 AM", "12:20 AM", "12:21 AM", "12:22 AM", "12:23 AM", "12:24 AM", "12:25 AM", "12:26 AM", "12:27 AM", "12:28 AM", "12:29 AM", "12:30 AM", "12:31 AM", "12:32 AM", "12:33 AM", "12:34 AM", "12:35 AM", "12:36 AM", "12:37 AM", "12:38 AM", "12:39 AM", "12:40 AM", "12:41 AM", "12:42 AM", "12:43 AM", "12:44 AM", "12:45 AM", "12:46 AM", "12:47 AM", "12:48 AM", "12:49 AM", "12:50 AM", "12:51 AM", "12:52 AM", "12:53 AM", "12:54 AM", "12:55 AM", "12:56 AM", "12:57 AM", "12:58 AM", "12:59 AM" };
    String[] AlarmPM = { "1:00 PM", "1:01 PM", "1:02 PM", "1:03 PM", "1:04 PM", "1:05 PM", "1:06 PM", "1:07 PM", "1:08 PM", "1:09 PM", "1:10 PM", "1:11 PM", "1:12 PM", "1:13 PM", "1:14 PM", "1:15 PM", "1:16 PM", "1:17 PM", "1:18 PM", "1:19 PM", "1:20 PM", "1:21 PM", "1:22 PM", "1:23 PM", "1:24 PM", "1:25 PM", "1:26 PM", "1:27 PM", "1:28 PM", "1:29 PM", "1:30 PM", "1:31 PM", "1:32 PM", "1:33 PM", "1:34 PM", "1:35 PM", "1:36 PM", "1:37 PM", "1:38 PM", "1:39 PM", "1:40 PM", "1:41 PM", "1:42 PM", "1:43 PM", "1:44 PM", "1:45 PM", "1:46 PM", "1:47 PM", "1:48 PM", "1:49 PM", "1:50 PM", "1:51 PM", "1:52 PM", "1:53 PM", "1:54 PM", "1:55 PM", "1:56 PM", "1:57 PM", "1:58 PM", "1:59 PM", "2:00 PM", "2:01 PM", "2:02 PM", "2:03 PM", "2:04 PM", "2:05 PM", "2:06 PM", "2:07 PM", "2:08 PM", "2:09 PM", "2:10 PM", "2:11 PM", "2:12 PM", "2:13 PM", "2:14 PM", "2:15 PM", "2:16 PM", "2:17 PM", "2:18 PM", "2:19 PM", "2:20 PM", "2:21 PM", "2:22 PM", "2:23 PM", "2:24 PM", "2:25 PM", "2:26 PM", "2:27 PM", "2:28 PM", "2:29 PM", "2:30 PM", "2:31 PM", "2:32 PM", "2:33 PM", "2:34 PM", "2:35 PM", "2:36 PM", "2:37 PM", "2:38 PM", "2:39 PM", "2:40 PM", "2:41 PM", "2:42 PM", "2:43 PM", "2:44 PM", "2:45 PM", "2:46 PM", "2:47 PM", "2:48 PM", "2:49 PM", "2:50 PM", "2:51 PM", "2:52 PM", "2:53 PM", "2:54 PM", "2:55 PM", "2:56 PM", "2:57 PM", "2:58 PM", "2:59 PM", "3:00 PM", "3:01 PM", "3:02 PM", "3:03 PM", "3:04 PM", "3:05 PM", "3:06 PM", "3:07 PM", "3:08 PM", "3:09 PM", "3:10 PM", "3:11 PM", "3:12 PM", "3:13 PM", "3:14 PM", "3:15 PM", "3:16 PM", "3:17 PM", "3:18 PM", "3:19 PM", "3:20 PM", "3:21 PM", "3:22 PM", "3:23 PM", "3:24 PM", "3:25 PM", "3:26 PM", "3:27 PM", "3:28 PM", "3:29 PM", "3:30 PM", "3:31 PM", "3:32 PM", "3:33 PM", "3:34 PM", "3:35 PM", "3:36 PM", "3:37 PM", "3:38 PM", "3:39 PM", "3:40 PM", "3:41 PM", "3:42 PM", "3:43 PM", "3:44 PM", "3:45 PM", "3:46 PM", "3:47 PM", "3:48 PM", "3:49 PM", "3:50 PM", "3:51 PM", "3:52 PM", "3:53 PM", "3:54 PM", "3:55 PM", "3:56 PM", "3:57 PM", "3:58 PM", "3:59 PM", "4:00 PM", "4:01 PM", "4:02 PM", "4:03 PM", "4:04 PM", "4:05 PM", "4:06 PM", "4:07 PM", "4:08 PM", "4:09 PM", "4:10 PM", "4:11 PM", "4:12 PM", "4:13 PM", "4:14 PM", "4:15 PM", "4:16 PM", "4:17 PM", "4:18 PM", "4:19 PM", "4:20 PM", "4:21 PM", "4:22 PM", "4:23 PM", "4:24 PM", "4:25 PM", "4:26 PM", "4:27 PM", "4:28 PM", "4:29 PM", "4:30 PM", "4:31 PM", "4:32 PM", "4:33 PM", "4:34 PM", "4:35 PM", "4:36 PM", "4:37 PM", "4:38 PM", "4:39 PM", "4:40 PM", "4:41 PM", "4:42 PM", "4:43 PM", "4:44 PM", "4:45 PM", "4:46 PM", "4:47 PM", "4:48 PM", "4:49 PM", "4:50 PM", "4:51 PM", "4:52 PM", "4:53 PM", "4:54 PM", "4:55 PM", "4:56 PM", "4:57 PM", "4:58 PM", "4:59 PM", "5:00 PM", "5:01 PM", "5:02 PM", "5:03 PM", "5:04 PM", "5:05 PM", "5:06 PM", "5:07 PM", "5:08 PM", "5:09 PM", "5:10 PM", "5:11 PM", "5:12 PM", "5:13 PM", "5:14 PM", "5:15 PM", "5:16 PM", "5:17 PM", "5:18 PM", "5:19 PM", "5:20 PM", "5:21 PM", "5:22 PM", "5:23 PM", "5:24 PM", "5:25 PM", "5:26 PM", "5:27 PM", "5:28 PM", "5:29 PM", "5:30 PM", "5:31 PM", "5:32 PM", "5:33 PM", "5:34 PM", "5:35 PM", "5:36 PM", "5:37 PM", "5:38 PM", "5:39 PM", "5:40 PM", "5:41 PM", "5:42 PM", "5:43 PM", "5:44 PM", "5:45 PM", "5:46 PM", "5:47 PM", "5:48 PM", "5:49 PM", "5:50 PM", "5:51 PM", "5:52 PM", "5:53 PM", "5:54 PM", "5:55 PM", "5:56 PM", "5:57 PM", "5:58 PM", "5:59 PM", "6:00 PM", "6:01 PM", "6:02 PM", "6:03 PM", "6:04 PM", "6:05 PM", "6:06 PM", "6:07 PM", "6:08 PM", "6:09 PM", "6:10 PM", "6:11 PM", "6:12 PM", "6:13 PM", "6:14 PM", "6:15 PM", "6:16 PM", "6:17 PM", "6:18 PM", "6:19 PM", "6:20 PM", "6:21 PM", "6:22 PM", "6:23 PM", "6:24 PM", "6:25 PM", "6:26 PM", "6:27 PM", "6:28 PM", "6:29 PM", "6:30 PM", "6:31 PM", "6:32 PM", "6:33 PM", "6:34 PM", "6:35 PM", "6:36 PM", "6:37 PM", "6:38 PM", "6:39 PM", "6:40 PM", "6:41 PM", "6:42 PM", "6:43 PM", "6:44 PM", "6:45 PM", "6:46 PM", "6:47 PM", "6:48 PM", "6:49 PM", "6:50 PM", "6:51 PM", "6:52 PM", "6:53 PM", "6:54 PM", "6:55 PM", "6:56 PM", "6:57 PM", "6:58 PM", "6:59 PM", "7:00 PM", "7:01 PM", "7:02 PM", "7:03 PM", "7:04 PM", "7:05 PM", "7:06 PM", "7:07 PM", "7:08 PM", "7:09 PM", "7:10 PM", "7:11 PM", "7:12 PM", "7:13 PM", "7:14 PM", "7:15 PM", "7:16 PM", "7:17 PM", "7:18 PM", "7:19 PM", "7:20 PM", "7:21 PM", "7:22 PM", "7:23 PM", "7:24 PM", "7:25 PM", "7:26 PM", "7:27 PM", "7:28 PM", "7:29 PM", "7:30 PM", "7:31 PM", "7:32 PM", "7:33 PM", "7:34 PM", "7:35 PM", "7:36 PM", "7:37 PM", "7:38 PM", "7:39 PM", "7:40 PM", "7:41 PM", "7:42 PM", "7:43 PM", "7:44 PM", "7:45 PM", "7:46 PM", "7:47 PM", "7:48 PM", "7:49 PM", "7:50 PM", "7:51 PM", "7:52 PM", "7:53 PM", "7:54 PM", "7:55 PM", "7:56 PM", "7:57 PM", "7:58 PM", "7:59 PM", "8:00 PM", "8:01 PM", "8:02 PM", "8:03 PM", "8:04 PM", "8:05 PM", "8:06 PM", "8:07 PM", "8:08 PM", "8:09 PM", "8:10 PM", "8:11 PM", "8:12 PM", "8:13 PM", "8:14 PM", "8:15 PM", "8:16 PM", "8:17 PM", "8:18 PM", "8:19 PM", "8:20 PM", "8:21 PM", "8:22 PM", "8:23 PM", "8:24 PM", "8:25 PM", "8:26 PM", "8:27 PM", "8:28 PM", "8:29 PM", "8:30 PM", "8:31 PM", "8:32 PM", "8:33 PM", "8:34 PM", "8:35 PM", "8:36 PM", "8:37 PM", "8:38 PM", "8:39 PM", "8:40 PM", "8:41 PM", "8:42 PM", "8:43 PM", "8:44 PM", "8:45 PM", "8:46 PM", "8:47 PM", "8:48 PM", "8:49 PM", "8:50 PM", "8:51 PM", "8:52 PM", "8:53 PM", "8:54 PM", "8:55 PM", "8:56 PM", "8:57 PM", "8:58 PM", "8:59 PM", "9:00 PM", "9:01 PM", "9:02 PM", "9:03 PM", "9:04 PM", "9:05 PM", "9:06 PM", "9:07 PM", "9:08 PM", "9:09 PM", "9:10 PM", "9:11 PM", "9:12 PM", "9:13 PM", "9:14 PM", "9:15 PM", "9:16 PM", "9:17 PM", "9:18 PM", "9:19 PM", "9:20 PM", "9:21 PM", "9:22 PM", "9:23 PM", "9:24 PM", "9:25 PM", "9:26 PM", "9:27 PM", "9:28 PM", "9:29 PM", "9:30 PM", "9:31 PM", "9:32 PM", "9:33 PM", "9:34 PM", "9:35 PM", "9:36 PM", "9:37 PM", "9:38 PM", "9:39 PM", "9:40 PM", "9:41 PM", "9:42 PM", "9:43 PM", "9:44 PM", "9:45 PM", "9:46 PM", "9:47 PM", "9:48 PM", "9:49 PM", "9:50 PM", "9:51 PM", "9:52 PM", "9:53 PM", "9:54 PM", "9:55 PM", "9:56 PM", "9:57 PM", "9:58 PM", "9:59 PM", "10:00 PM", "10:01 PM", "10:02 PM", "10:03 PM", "10:04 PM", "10:05 PM", "10:06 PM", "10:07 PM", "10:08 PM", "10:09 PM", "10:10 PM", "10:11 PM", "10:12 PM", "10:13 PM", "10:14 PM", "10:15 PM", "10:16 PM", "10:17 PM", "10:18 PM", "10:19 PM", "10:20 PM", "10:21 PM", "10:22 PM", "10:23 PM", "10:24 PM", "10:25 PM", "10:26 PM", "10:27 PM", "10:28 PM", "10:29 PM", "10:30 PM", "10:31 PM", "10:32 PM", "10:33 PM", "10:34 PM", "10:35 PM", "10:36 PM", "10:37 PM", "10:38 PM", "10:39 PM", "10:40 PM", "10:41 PM", "10:42 PM", "10:43 PM", "10:44 PM", "10:45 PM", "10:46 PM", "10:47 PM", "10:48 PM", "10:49 PM", "10:50 PM", "10:51 PM", "10:52 PM", "10:53 PM", "10:54 PM", "10:55 PM", "10:56 PM", "10:57 PM", "10:58 PM", "10:59 PM", "11:00 PM", "11:01 PM", "11:02 PM", "11:03 PM", "11:04 PM", "11:05 PM", "11:06 PM", "11:07 PM", "11:08 PM", "11:09 PM", "11:10 PM", "11:11 PM", "11:12 PM", "11:13 PM", "11:14 PM", "11:15 PM", "11:16 PM", "11:17 PM", "11:18 PM", "11:19 PM", "11:20 PM", "11:21 PM", "11:22 PM", "11:23 PM", "11:24 PM", "11:25 PM", "11:26 PM", "11:27 PM", "11:28 PM", "11:29 PM", "11:30 PM", "11:31 PM", "11:32 PM", "11:33 PM", "11:34 PM", "11:35 PM", "11:36 PM", "11:37 PM", "11:38 PM", "11:39 PM", "11:40 PM", "11:41 PM", "11:42 PM", "11:43 PM", "11:44 PM", "11:45 PM", "11:46 PM", "11:47 PM", "11:48 PM", "11:49 PM", "11:50 PM", "11:51 PM", "11:52 PM", "11:53 PM", "11:54 PM", "11:55 PM", "11:56 PM", "11:57 PM", "11:58 PM", "11:59 PM", "12:00 PM", "12:01 PM", "12:02 PM", "12:03 PM", "12:04 PM", "12:05 PM", "12:06 PM", "12:07 PM", "12:08 PM", "12:09 PM", "12:10 PM", "12:11 PM", "12:12 PM", "12:13 PM", "12:14 PM", "12:15 PM", "12:16 PM", "12:17 PM", "12:18 PM", "12:19 PM", "12:20 PM", "12:21 PM", "12:22 PM", "12:23 PM", "12:24 PM", "12:25 PM", "12:26 PM", "12:27 PM", "12:28 PM", "12:29 PM", "12:30 PM", "12:31 PM", "12:32 PM", "12:33 PM", "12:34 PM", "12:35 PM", "12:36 PM", "12:37 PM", "12:38 PM", "12:39 PM", "12:40 PM", "12:41 PM", "12:42 PM", "12:43 PM", "12:44 PM", "12:45 PM", "12:46 PM", "12:47 PM", "12:48 PM", "12:49 PM", "12:50 PM", "12:51 PM", "12:52 PM", "12:53 PM", "12:54 PM", "12:55 PM", "12:56 PM", "12:57 PM", "12:58 PM", "12:59 PM" };
    String AlarmTime;
```

then I add the form1 objects

```
_recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(AlarmClock_SpeechRecognized);
        _recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(AlarmAM))));
        _recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(AlarmPM))));


if (Settings.Default.AClockEnbl == true)
        { AlarmTimer.Enabled = true; }
```

then I add the magic

```
private void AlarmClock_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        string speech = e.Result.Text;
        if (speech == "set the alarm")
        { AlarmTime = "set"; Alexis.SpeakAsync("What time?"); }
        if (AlarmTime == "set")
        {
            foreach (string time in AlarmAM)
            {
                if (speech == time)
                { AlarmTimer.Enabled = true; Alexis.SpeakAsync("Alarm set for " + time); Settings.Default.Alarm = time; }
            }
            foreach (string time in AlarmPM)
            {
                if (speech == time)
                { AlarmTimer.Enabled = true; Alexis.SpeakAsync("Alarm set for " + time); Settings.Default.Alarm = time; }
            }
        }
        if (speech == "clear the alarm")
        { Settings.Default.Alarm = String.Empty; AlarmTimer.Enabled = false; Alexis.SpeakAsync("The alarm is no longer set"); }
        if (speech == "what time is the alarm")
        { Alexis.SpeakAsync(Settings.Default.Alarm); }
    }
```

Comment: If you look at this answer, I had to add every single time into a string[] and then I could load it. Which took a long time to do. It would be the same thing and concept. Also you have a timer event with this. You can also add to this and make multiple alarms.

Comment: that's very nifty. I see what you did to keep track of the current conversation context in order to accept the next commands. Thanks man. It's a way forward and a lot of help.

Comment: your welcome and always able to help. I am in the process of tweaking my Desktop Recorder but I have not figured out an answer or solution as of yet.. So I give myself a break from coding to look at coding on here.. Also with the speech with the commands or context once you implement the events you can pretty much do anything that's the hard part and always copy and paste saves you a lot of time unless you just like to type.